# Why can't Whole Module Optimalization infer final on public non-overridden module classes/methods in the same module?

Tags: swift

From [this article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27), I quote the following sentence:

> Use Whole Module Optimization to infer final on internal declarations.
>   Declarations with internal access (the default if nothing is declared)
>   are only visible within the module where they are declared. Because
>   Swift normally compiles the files that make up a module separately,
>   the compiler cannot ascertain whether or not an internal declaration
>   is overridden in a different file. However, if Whole Module
>   Optimization is enabled, all of the module is compiled together at the
>   same time. This allows the compiler to make inferences about the
>   entire module together and infer final on declarations with internal
>   if there are no visible overrides.
>        Let’s go back to the original code snippet, this time adding some extra public keywords to ParticleModel.

```
public class ParticleModel {
    var point = ( x: 0.0, y: 0.0 )
    var velocity = 100.0

    func updatePoint(newPoint: (Double, Double), newVelocity: Double) {
        point = newPoint
        velocity = newVelocity
    }

    public func update(newP: (Double, Double), newV: Double) {
        updatePoint(newP, newVelocity: newV)
    }
}

var p = ParticleModel()
for i in stride(from: 0.0, through: times, by: 1.0) {
    p.update((i * sin(i), i), newV:i*1000)
}
```

> When compiling this snippet with Whole Module Optimization the
>   compiler can infer final on the properties point, velocity, and the
>   method call updatePoint(). In contrast, **it can not be inferred that
>   update() is final since update() has public access**.

Why can't WMO static dispatch a call to `update()` if `ParticalModel` isn't overridden in the current module? It is not allowed to override `ParicleModel` in other modules (since it's access modifier is `public`, not `open`). I would expect that every method and property in the class can have `final` inferred because it isn't overridden in the current module, but the documentation explicitly mentions that it can not infer `final`.

Comment: Note that the linked article predates the introduction of the `open` access level, so what was `public` then had the same semantics as what is now `open`. You're right that a call to a `public` member should now be statically dispatched with WMO if it's not overriden within the module.

Comment: @Hamish Ow thats sounds logical. That would be a fine answer as well :)

Comment: I was here to ask literally the same question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked article was written for Swift 2, which predates the introduction of the `open` access level in Swift 3 ([SE-0117](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md)). Therefore what it refers to as `public` is now semantically what the `open` access level is. You're indeed correct that a call to a `public` member will now be statically dispatched with whole module optimisation enabled if the compiler can prove it is not overriden within the same module.